# Google Translate Save to Phrasebook Import - GET/POST Hack

Tags: post, get, firebug, google-translate

I have bunch of words saved in plain text file and a I would like to import them to Google Translate somehow. They should then be visible in new Google Translate feature, Phrasebook. So what I did so far is that I've opened Google Translate page with enabled FireBug and enter word "feuds". The results are following:

```
GET /translate/releases/twsfe_w_20130506_RC02/r/js/desktop_module_lazy.js
GET /translate/releases/twsfe_w_20130506_RC02/r/js/desktop_module_lazy.js
GET /translate_a/t?client=t&hl=en&sl=auto&tl=sk&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&multires=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&uptl=sk&sc=1&q=feuds
POST https://plus.google.com/u/0/_/n/gcosuc?origin=http%3A%2F%2Ftranslate.google.com
200 OK
103ms   
>>>
################################################
### AFTER PRESSING SAVE TO PHRASEBOOK BUTTON ###
################################################
POST /translate_a/sg?client=t&cm=a&sl=en&tl=sk&ql=5&hl=en&xt=ALkJrhgAAAAAUZvTtWm7IqJAYJpay1AU8x-VoS_AM0J0
client  t
cm  a
hl  en
ql  5
sl  en
tl  sk
xt  ALkJrhgAAAAAUZvTtWm7IqJAYJpay1AU8x-VoS_AM0J0
200 OK
137ms   
>>>
GET /translate_a/sg?client=t&cm=g&tk=8mXp7vd2yN4UVnN8_Bw51LnXE2wqfQI&hl=en&xt=ALkJrhgAAAAAUZvTtWm7IqJAYJpay1AU8x-VoS_AM0J0
client  t
cm  g
hl  en
tk  8mXp7vd2yN4UVnN8_Bw51LnXE2wqfQI
xt  ALkJrhgAAAAAUZvTtWm7IqJAYJpay1AU8x-VoS_AM0J0
200 OK
112ms   
>>>
```

You can see that on 3rd GET the word is available "&q=feuds" But what happens when I press "Save to Phrasebook"? It seems that there is sending source language (sl), target language (tl) etc. with some strange string: "ALkJrhgAAAAAUZvTtWm7IqJAYJpay1AU8x-VoS_AM0J0" which might be my "hashed" word. Another idea which comes to my mind is that this strange string did not have to bee "hashed" word necessary, but it might be for example some ID, which refers to word that I have typed in the past (in this case few seconds ago until I hit "Save to Phrasebook" button). Is it possible to somehow "decode" this string?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that this "xt" value is received in 1st response from "translate.google.com", look for variable with name "USAGE". 
Also I have found that "xt" value appear in all requests related to Phrasebook (example: show phrasebook, add/delete word to/from phrasebook), and in each new google translator page you will have new "xt" value.

Based on this, can assume, that "xt" variable implement function of identification token for Phrasebook.